# How to encapsulate two stream buffers

Tags: c++, stream, std, iostream, ofstream

`std::cout.rdbuf()` is so easy to use. But I wish to print string to console as well as write it to a file.

So what I am thinking of is to encapsulate two stream buffers into a derived class of `std::streambuf`, and pass this to `rdbuf()`. Is that possible?

How should I accomplish that?

Comment: Sounds like what boost already provides as [boost::iostreams::tee](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iostreams/doc/functions/tee.html)

Comment: @Cubbi Good idea. Never knew about that.

Answer (score 1):

I think a better way to do this would be to encapsulate two streams into an actual stream class derived from `std::basic_ostream<...>`.

Something for a start would be:

```
template<class charT, class traits = std::char_traits<charT>>
class basic_binary_stream : public std::basic_osteam<charT>
{
    typedef std::basic_ostream<charT> stream_type;
    typedef std::char_traits<charT>   traits_type;
    /* ... */
public:
    binary_stream(stream_type& o1, stream_type& o2)
        : s1(o1), s2(o2)
    { }

    binary_stream& operator<<(int n)
    {
        s1 << n;
        s2 << n;
        return *this;
    }

    /* ... */
private:
    stream_type& s1, &s2;
};

using binary_stream = basic_binary_stream<char>;
```